# Youtube V3 API PHP Issues

Tags: youtube-api

I have managed to get a valid OAuth 2 token using the Google API for Youtube, but for some reason when making a request, either in my code (PHP) or in the test tools within the Youtube API (for example : https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) , I keep getting the following error :

```
[errors] => Array(
  [0] => Array(
     [domain] => youtube.header
     [reason] => youtubeSignupRequired
     [message] => Unauthorized
     [locationType] => header
     [location] => Authorization
  )
)
[code] => 401
[message] => Unauthorized
```

OR

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }],
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Access Not Configured"
  }
}
```

Can anyone please advise ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means you have not yet enabled the YouTube Data API. 401 and 403 mean completely different things, however, so here's a checklist of things I would look for:

1. Verify that you have enabled the YouTube Data API in the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). It'll be under "Services". You'll need to flip them on. We did a [short video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im69kzhpR3I&list=PLhBgTdAWkxeB-zCekGukAo0DzmpwBiua2) about how to enable and retrieve developer keys.
2. If you're making an API call to upload videos or edit playlists, you'll need the account you're [authorizing as to have a linked channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1646861?hl=en).

When these are done, you'll be able to download and run the PHP samples. We have a [tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMhN6pCAZWo&list=PLhBgTdAWkxeB-zCekGukAo0DzmpwBiua2) for that as well.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, unfortunately both points have been taking care of before even posting this question.

Comment: "youtubeSignupRequired" seems to imply that the channel is not linked, but I can't say for sure because I don't know what API call you are making. Can you clarify your question?